# Music not working in Python/Pygame

Tags: python, audio, pygame, subprocess

I tried looking it up and there is multiple solution, but **none of them work for me**.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('Pickle.aifc')
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)

display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Music Test")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
            exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

throws the error

```
  File "/Users/William/PycharmProjects/My Games/Examples/MusicTest/OkayOnceMore.py", line 6, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load('Pickle.aifc')
pygame.error: Unrecognized file type (not AIFF)
```

I also found this thing where I can do this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['afplay', 'Pickle.aifc'])
```

in my pygame project **however** I cannot stop this in the middle of it even when I put it in a Thread. Any solutions?

Ps: I am using mac 10.11.6

Update: I made a copy of pickle.aifc and converted it into pickle.aiff, I am still getting a very similar error:

```
  File "/Users/William/PycharmProjects/My Games/Examples/MusicTest/Main.py", line 12, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load('Pickle.aiff')
pygame.error: Unrecognized file type (not AIFF)
```

Comment: It doesn't accept .aifc file only .aiff

Comment: Have you tried converting to ogg vorbis (which https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html seems to recommend as the most supported format)

Comment: Try converting your audio file through online converters. There are many of them available for free on net. Link :  http://online-audio-converter.com/ (may work)

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation Pygame canbot handle file formats such as .aiffc.

A solution would be to convert your file to .wav here: https://cloudconvert.com/aifc-to-wav

Comment: I get the same message when I do though, **the exact same message**